# Why Metasploit not being able to establish Meterpreter sessions?

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, metasploit

I am entirely new in Linux. I have set up a pen-testing lab with Kali Linux 1.1.0b, windows xp sp3, and, Metasploitable 2 Linux.

PostgreSQL and Metasploit services are running well. But, the Metasploit framework in Kali is not being able to establish Meterpreter sessions. I tried over and over again and left no Youtube tutorial video untouched.

How to diagnose problems of Metasploit not being able to establish Meterpreter sessions?

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to configure your postgreql and createdb and import your db into your pg, if your postgresql is running , it's not everything ok.please configure `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: metasploit is able to connect to postgresql. I finding that running ok.

Comment: Do youu have db for and user for metasploit for it?

Comment: It's better to run `psql` and direct test.

Comment: please provide me a tutorial link. i don't even know what psql is.

Comment: Dear BROY, you can use http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node150.html , But i have a suggesstion for you and everyone to start kali linux: be sure you need kali for security issue, It's very good solution, But you need to know base of unix/linux to work every linux or unix, i reccommend you learn base of linux.